# anyone has a solution for this gcc compiler error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments but takes just two

Tags: c++, gcc

This is my code:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Compare>
inline const _Tp&
inline min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare& __comp)
{
   if (__comp(__b, __a))
    return __b ;
  return __a;
}
```

this is the error message I am getting:

> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:232:57: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2

I understand I am passing 3 arguments a,b and comp but I am only returning a and b, however when I try to return comp it gives me the same message.

Comment: Are you including `<windows.h>` or something?

Comment: You probably have a `using namespace std;` somewhere. But is that really your code? It looks almost like a standard library implementation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realize that was yours because of the libstdc++ness of it. The solution is to use `std::min` and not yours.

Comment: Looks like you need an `#undef min` somewhere.

Comment: Hi all, Juanchopanza is right this is not my code this is the code on stl_algobase.h file that is part of a standard library. However, the compiler is throwing me a bunch of errors from that file and I do not understand why. I do have a "using namespace std, in my mysqpl.cpp code Is that what is causing this problem?

Comment: Hi again everyone, the problem was not the use of "using namespace std;" I got red of it and I still get the same compiling errors does anyone has an idea or solution to the problem?

Comment: Hi again Bryan Chen got the right answer. However, I still get compiling errors from .h files that belong to standard libraries does anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You have `#define min(a, b)` somewhere, so pre-processor try to expand it and failed

Try `(min)(a, b, compare)`. The parentheses around `min` prevent macro expansion.

Comment: Next step: file a bug report for the code that `#define`'d min.

Comment: Thank you Bryan I use the parentheses and it did the trick I am not getting that error anymore. However, I keep on getting errors from .h files that belong to standard libraries is that normal? I have never seen something like that what you think I am doing wrong may be something on my command line to compile I am using :          g++ mysql.cpp -o mysql -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/c++/4.4/ -L/usr/lib/mysql -libmysqlclient -libz                                                                 I think I may missing something or adding something wrong

Comment: Thank you to all that try to help me answer the question the problem was on the machine I just change to another one and now is working fine. However I can not ask any more questions because I was blocked out by the stackoverflow Admin. –  Ledys Sanchez 27 secs ago   edit   Thank you to all that try to help me answer the question the problem was on the machine I just change to another on and now is working fine. However I can not ask any more questions because I was blocked out by the stackoverflow Admin.